# Changing MKMapView Center coordinate at a different speed then its region.span

Tags: swift, mkmapview, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to make my map view have a custom animation whenever an annotation on the map is selected.

This custom animation needs to consist of the map view's center coordinate changing at a different speed than the map view's span. (I want the map view to simultaneously quickly adjust its center then zoom in slowly after)

I've managed to somewhat accomplish this by performing the animations one after another like so:

```
MKMapView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.homeMapView.centerCoordinate = region.center
    }, completion: {
        (value: Bool) in
        MKMapView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.homeMapView.region.span = region.span
        }, completion: {
            (value: Bool) in
            print ("finished animation")
        })
    })
```

The problem is, this does not look smooth and I would ideally like both animations starting at the same time and running concurrently. This could be accomplished with a CAAnimation and the center coordinate value being additive while the span changes, but unfortunately I'm dealing with a MKMapView not a CALayer.

Any ideas or help would be much appreciated! Thanks!